# ReadFile only reading one buffer character?

Tags: c++, winapi, file-io, readfile

I'm writing a program to communicate to a motor drive through a virtual com port via USB.  I'm making use of the windows.h file-io to communicate with it (CreateFile, WriteFile, ReadFile). I can write to the drive perfectly fine, but I run into an issue when trying to read from it. For some reason, the ReadFile only seems to read in one character from the buffer. Here's my code:

```
#define READ_BUFF_SIZE 500
#define READ_TIMEOUT 5000
void ReadInput(HANDLE hComm)
{
    DWORD dwRead, dwRes;
    BOOL fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
    OVERLAPPED osReader = {0};
    char lpBuf[READ_BUFF_SIZE] = {0};

    osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL);
    if(osReader.hEvent==NULL){
        cerr<<"Error creating overlapped handle!";return;}

    if(!fWaitingOnRead){
        if(!ReadFile(hComm, lpBuf, READ_BUFF_SIZE, &dwRead, &osReader)){
            if(GetLastError()!=ERROR_IO_PENDING)
                {cout<<"Error: "<<GetLastError()<<endl;return;}
            else
                fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
        }
        else {cout<<"a\n";PrintInput(lpBuf,dwRead);}
    }

    if(fWaitingOnRead){
        dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(osReader.hEvent,READ_TIMEOUT);
        cout<<"\n\nAfter WaitForSingleObject."<<endl;
        switch(dwRes)
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            if(!GetOverlappedResult(hComm,&osReader,&dwRead,TRUE))
                cout<<"Error in Comm"<<endl;
            else
                {cout<<"b\n\n";PrintInput(lpBuf,dwRead);}
            fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
            break;

        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            cout<<"wait timeout"<<endl;
            break;

        default:
            cout<<"Default Case"<<endl;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

dwRead always seems to be set to 1. I'll get the first character that the drive outputs (an apostrophe), but it won't read the rest. I've found some workarounds in that if I modify it to expect only one character and then loop through the reading, it will perform.
Additionally, I need the query the drive for a response, so before calling this ReadInput function, I have to call a WriteBuffer to send a character. If I put a delay (~10-50ms) between the read and write calls, it reads the whole thing.

Anyone have any ideas on this? It's not a huge issue since I've found some workarounds, but it has been bothering me for the past few days.

**Edit:** Clarification for tinman's questions.

Comment: I think you need to use the value of dwRead after calling GetOverlappedResult as it is only then that the amount of data transferred gets copied into your variable. If that doesn't work, what is your READ_BUFF_SIZE defined as? What are your com port timeouts set to?

Comment: Yeah, that print statement is only there as an indicator of when I enter that loop; printing dwRead is useless, I just don't bother to get rid of it. I do see dwRead is 1 when it's passed to PrintInput (which simply prints the string and dwRead).  READ_BUFF_SIZE is defined as 500, READ_TIMEOUT is 5000. My COMMTIMEOUTS are set to fairly large values.

Comment: Drivers that emulate a serial port are notoriously crappy.  You are not actually taking advantage of overlapped I/O since you immediately call WFSO, avoid giving the driver the exercise.

Comment: Hans: Thanks, but I'm not sure if that's related. I'll get the same behavior even when using non-overlapped I/O.

Comment: have you considered just polling the COM port?

Comment: Code Monkey: No? I honestly started this project a few days ago and it's my first venture into COM Port communication. If you have any other methods/suggestions, I'd love to hear them to go research them myself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `SetCommTimeouts` with appropriate settings. Here is some code that I use. You should look at the MSDN documentation for `COMMTIMEOUTS` structure.

```
// Only use read interval timeout. Do not use total read/write timeout.
COMMTIMEOUTS commtimeouts = { min((1000 + GetBaudrate() - 1) / GetBaudrate(), 1), 0, 0, 0, 0 };
SetCommTimeouts(m_hFile, &commtimeouts);
```

Of course you could also provide a total read timeout instead of an interval timeout.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx): When reading from a communications device, the behavior of `ReadFile` is determined by the current communication time-out as set and retrieved by using the `SetCommTimeouts` and `GetCommTimeouts` functions. Unpredictable results can occur if you fail to set the time-out values. For more information about communication time-outs, see `COMMTIMEOUTS`.